# Could you help me with page numbering?

Tags: header-footer, titles, page-numbering, pagestyle

How can I make page numbering starting from the first page, but also, at the same time except the header..so the numbering starts regularly..but header starts from the second page?
When I use `\thispagestyle{empty}` it applies to both.

My code:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.08,trim={0.30mm 0.30mm 0.30mm 0.30mm},clip=true]{picture.pdf}} 
\lhead{\small{\textsc{Name}}} 
\lfoot{} 
\cfoot{\thepage} 
\rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.35pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 

\begin{document} 
\setcounter{page}{1} 
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable short tex code with dummy text so that we can see your used documentclass and which package you used for building the header and footer ...

Comment: And the used documentclass is ??????

Comment: article,it's for a project

Comment: well,I fixed it,with \thispagestyle{plain} instead of  \thispagestyle{empty}

Comment: Good, feel free to write an self-answer, it is welcome here.

Comment: I’m not sure now what issue you were asking about. I thought you were wondering why the page number reset to 1, but apparently that’s something you did on purpose by resetting the page counter?

Comment: No,just wanted to remove header from my first page.,but keep a number of page on it. Sorry about that btw